# How can I divide two columns and show results per row?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would not be able to do what I want :(, I explain:

I have two tables:

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmfGx.png)

[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQjwx.png)

I am looking for a query where I can get FALSE/(FALSE+TRUE).

So far I managed to do it over the total using this:

```
select 
(select count(*) from (select Drink from Table1
where Drink=False)) as F,
(select count(*) from (select Drink from Table1
where Drink=True)) as T,
(F/(F+T)) as total
```

With that I can get the total of the column I want, I just have to change, if I want, Drink-->Food.

But now I would like the final result by Country, that is, something similar to this:

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vggdj.png)

In order not to break the forum rules, I'll leave what I've tried so far:

```
select * from (select distinct t2.Country_Name, count(t1.Drink)
from Table 1 t1
left join Table 2 t2 on t2.Country_ID=t1.Country_ID
where Drink=False
group by t2.Country_Name) as F
union
select * from (select distinct t2.Country_Name, count(t1.Drink)
from Table 1 t1
left join Table 2 t2 on t2.Country_ID=t1.Country_ID
where Drink=True
group by t2.Country_Name) as T
```

But it doesn't even bring me what I expect :(

I don't know if it helps much, but I'm using Snowflake

Any help is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Reading the answer in that publication, then, no matter how small the example, is it always advisable to put the table in text? Understood, I thought that for these cases an image was more comfortable. I'll keep it in mind for the next one, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query could be simpliefied using COUNT_IF:

```
SELECT COUNT_IF(Drink=False)/COUNT(*)
FROM Table1;
```

---

Grouped by Country:

```
SELECT t2.Country_Name, COUNT_IF(t1.Drink=False)/COUNT(*)
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t2
  ON t2.Country_ID=t1.Country_ID
GROUP BY t2.Country_Name;
```